# Not able to display image in ejs template. I am using express file uploader, mongodb, express, node, ejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs, blogs

I am able to upload image and store in db and uploads folder as well but can't display the image in ejs html template dynamically. I can show image if I give direct url path like `src="/uploads/final.jpg"` however I need the image dynamically here.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please do not post screenshots of your code. instead, post the relevant parts of your code here, thanks!
what exactly did not work? did you get an error message? or did the image just did not show up? if so, did you inspect the resulting html to see what the path looks like?

Comment: <img src= "/uploads/<%=post.filename%>"  alt="" width="100%" height="225" background="#55595c" color="#eceeef" class="card-img-top" text="Thumbnail" >

Comment: image not showing when i use above code on album page

Comment: yes, but what does the rendered html look like?

Comment: <img src="/uploads/ " alt="" width="100%" height="225" background="#55595c" color="#eceeef" class="card-img-top" text="Thumbnail">

Comment: it rendered above code

Comment: with blank space in image place

Comment: dynamic part of title is working fine but unable form dynamic url image folder path

Comment: if you want to modify i can give you files so that yoou can understand

Comment: i do understand i think... it seems your variable `post.path` is empty.
 you can try to output  `post.path` instead of the title and see what says...

Comment: Not able to set , can you please help me through git hub repository

Comment: I am trying it solve from 4 days onwards , not getting results

Answer (score 0):

please look at your schema, it's:

```
const postSchema = {
titel: String,
constent: String,
file: String
}
```

it says `file` not `path`, so:

`<%=post.file%>`

should work